# How to arrange Data in html table with jquery pagination?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table with jquery pagination. In that table there is a column witch contains dates. I want to get same dates in a same month to a one perticular page. Likewise each pages should have same dates in a same month.
For example:
page 1 - Dates of November
page 2 - Dates of May
page 3 - Dates of April
Table data loaded from sql server database.
According to pagination 10 table records per page.
Here is my jquery code

```
  //Add pagination fuctionality
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var myTable = document.getElementById('openDispatchNoteTable');

        for (var i = 0 ; i < myTable.rows.length ; i++) {
            if (myTable.rows[i].cells[6].innerText == myTable.rows[i + 1].cells[6].innerText)
                console.log("date : " + myTable.rows[i].cells[6].innerText);
            else
                console.log("date : Not equal")
            //console.log("date : " + myTable.rows[i].cells[6].innerText.split("-",3));
             //console.log("date " + i);
        }

        for (var i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
            $('.list-group').append('<li class="list-group-item"> Item ' + i + '</li>');

        }

        $('.table tbody').paginathing({
            limitPagination: false,
            perPage: 10,
            insertAfter: '.table',
            containerClass: 'panel-footer'
        });
    });
```

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In advance, I'm sorry that this is actually a comment, but as I cannot place them yet, i'll try it this way.

I'd rather use the library Datatables for these kind of sorting tables.
Datatables provide a wide range of options for sorting their tables.
Check it out [here](https://datatables.net/)